# If $f = O(x^{c+a})$ for all $a>0$ then is $f = O(x^c \log x)$?

Tags: number-theory, real-analysis

I was wondering if $f(x)=O(x^{c+a})$ for all $a>0$ then is it necessarily true that $f(x)=O(x^c\log x)$?
I suspect it's not true but want to know why.  (I know the converse is true.)

Any help is much appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: I think another example is (x^c)logxlogx

Answer (score 6):

Consider $f(x) = x^c (\log x)^b$, where $b>1$. This function is $O(x^{(c+a)})$ but it is not $O(x^c \log x)$.

Comment: I don't quite see how f is big O of x^(c+a) for all a>0.  How does one show it?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x) = (\log x)^2$.